# Why do certain captain-level Shinigami wield small zanpakuto?

Tags: bleach

In Bleach, it is stated that the size of Shinigami's zanpakuto (sword) is based on their spiritual ability.

However, many strong Shinigami have smaller swords. Sui-Feng, for example, has a zanpakuto that resembles a wakizashi, which is a relatively small sword. Why does this happen?

Comment: retroactive contunity

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because a shinigami's sword isn't based on their spiritual ability *alone*.

It also depends on the amount of control they have over their power. Ichigo's sword was larger, but it was also brittle, out of focus if you may.

> Ichigo's father [stated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIAEe.jpg) that a huge zanpakuto means nothing, and that if they had no control, all captains would have skyscraper sized zanpakuto.

Comment: When Ichigo first uses his banki against kuchiki mentioned that Ichigo's blade was smaller so he could move faster.

Answer (score 2):

Since Captains have immense spiritual power, their zanpakuto also have potentially huge size and power. As mentioned in another answer, their ability to control their power results in a small sealed zanpakuto.

However, their Shikai (initial release) and Bankai (final release) can cause their zanpakuto size to increase, because they are no longer concealing its power. See, for example:

- Large Shikai ([Kyouraku Shunsui](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Shunsui_Ky%C5%8Draku#Zanpakut.C5.8D), [Ichimaru Gin](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Gin_Ichimaru#Zanpakut.C5.8D), [Kuchiki Byakuya](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Byakuya_Kuchiki#Zanpakut.C5.8D), [Unohana Retsu](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Retsu_Unohana#Zanpakut.C5.8D))
- Large creatures as Bankai ([Kurotsuchi Mayuri](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Mayuri_Kurotsuchi#Zanpakut.C5.8D), [Komamura Sajin](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Sajin_Komamura#Zanpakut.C5.8D), [Abarai Renji](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Renji_Abarai#Zanpakut.C5.8D))
- Other Bankai with great volume ([Kuchiki Byakuya](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Byakuya_Kuchiki#Zanpakut.C5.8D), [Tousen Kaname](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Kaname_T%C5%8Dsen#Zanpakut.C5.8D), [Suì-Fēng](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Su%C3%AC-F%C4%93ng#Zanpakut.C5.8D))

At greater stages of release, the form of the zanpakuto depends greatly on its specific abilities, but there is a potential for huge size.

Comment: I wouldn't say that Kyouraku's shikai is "large"...

Comment: hmm, the [blades](http://www.bleachportal.net/info/images/kyouraku_shikai.jpg) seem to be as tall as him... isn't that rather large? Admittedly not as large as the other examples I listed, but the question was asked about zanpakuto sizes so I think "large as compared to usual swords" should count.

Answer (score 0):

Captain Class Shinigami and above have the ability to control the size of their zanpakuto, they all make them far smaller than their spiritual energy would make them to avoid carrying around a stupidly big sword.